What anchors should I use to install polycarbonate hurricane panels on stucco?
Want to install 5/8" polycarbonate hurricane panels over windows. The wall is 1/2" stucco over 3/4 plywood in my lanai.
I was thinking of crocodile anchor or similar zinc anchor that accepts 1/4-20 sidewalk bolt.
Any suggestions for installing in wood here? Will zinc plated rust even with nylon screws covering them in off season?

If the zinc covering is removed from the base steel, is where rust begins.  Nylon will not stop rust, but might protect the zinc from being damaged.  If the zinc is damaged, you need to cover with paint/heavy grease.

They make stainless steel sidewalk bolts and anchors by the way

Stucco doee not adhere well to wood, so there's no point in anchoring to it. At least uses a toggle bolt on 3/4" plywood, and, better, screw into structural member.
